# Google map's lat and lng to Bing coordinates

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

I have in database latitude and longitude coordinates that were created according to Google maps.

I'm wondering what is the difference in Google Maps' coordinates and Bing Maps' coordinates?
Is there any simple/automatic way how to convert those?

Answer (score 0):

there is no difference, you can use the same coordinates with both maps.

Comment: will it always point to the exactly same place? my problem is that areas of interest in my case are very well covered with bing maps however, google doesn't have any street marked there.
And unfortunately, it's much easier to make me indexing and marking with google maps php lib and on the front end to display data with bing maps.

Comment: Of course I can't tell you if it will always point to exactly the same place(there are many points on a map and I didn't check any ^^ ), but as both maps use the same projection, I don't know why there should be any differences.

Comment: thank you... you were right. I tested right now in many cases, it's quite same. On the end, i gave up from google maps, my region is simply not covered properly.

Comment: Both platforms are using WGS84 as coordinate systems.